# Generalized sorting algorithm on partially ordered set generated by a relation

Tags: algorithms, sorting, partial-order

Assume we have a finite set $X$ of elements and any relation $\preceq$ on $X$. Such a relation may or may not generate a reflexive transitive anti-symmetric relation $\leq$ on $X$ (a partial order). Recall:

*reflexive*: We always have $x\leq x$.

*transitive*: If $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z$ then also $x\leq z$.

*anti-symmetric*: If $x\leq y$ and $y\leq x$ then $x=y$.

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm that decides whether $\preceq$ extends to a partial order and if yes, returns one or one with uniform probability or all possible orderings of $X$ which respect the partial order.

This naturally decomposes into two subtasks (not claiming that the best algorithm decomposes this way):

1. Decision whether $\preceq$ extends to $\leq$ or, in other words, extending by transitivity does not violate anti-symmetry. If it does, describing the partial order $\leq$.
2. Finding the possible orderings.

The second points is related [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11276/extracting-the-set-of-chains-from-a-partial-order) question.

Comment: What is "it" in "If it exists"? ​ ​

Comment: Topological sort?

Comment: By "it" I mean the generated partial order. Of course I am wrong when stating that the equivalence classes are totally ordered sets, I have to edit the question (which I will do soon). But thanks Nicholas Mancuso, I guess topological sort is the keyword I was looking for and I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can efficiently test whether $\preceq$ extends to a partial order using topological sorting.  Form a directed graph with vertex set $X$ and with an edge $x \to y$ whenever we have $x \preceq y$ and $x \ne y$.  Then $\preceq$ extends to a partial order if and only if this graph has no cycles, which can be checked in linear time (e.g., by topologically sorting the graph).

Moreover, we can describe a minimal partial order $\le$ that is consistent with $\preceq$, as follows.  Compute the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of this graph. Now declare $x \le y$ iff there's an edge $x \to y$ in the transitive closure, or $x=y$.  (Equivalently, declare $x \le y$ iff $y$ is reachable from $x$ in zero or more steps, in the graph derived from $\preceq$.)  By construction, the relation $\le$ defined in this way will automatically be reflexive and transitive; if the original graph has no cycles, then it is easy to prove that the relation $\le$ will be anti-symmetric as well and thus will be a partial order.